# How can I rig a character with separated body parts?

Tags: rigging, armature

I'm new to rigging and I made a simple cubic character:
[image: cubic character]

To make it look simple, I removed some parts like the neck, the shoulders and the wrists, but when I try to generate a rig with Rigify or Mixamo, it fails.
Does someone have an idea how to make a functional rig for this character?

[Download Blend](https://mega.nz/file/4OgQlJAZ#ZsqBNlfi2hifOTG0rfH0-vSsOGhgL_7fqha0lmdnKuQ)

Comment: If you want to keep separate objects, the way to rig is to select the object, shift select the armature, switch to Pose mode, select the bone to which you want to parent, and Ctrl P > (Set Parent to) Bone. It looks like you're french, you can join use on this Discord: https://discord.gg/E6wXbR7A5S

Comment: Thank you it was exactly what i want ! I didn't know that we could link just one bone to an object

Comment: @moonboots please add this comment as an answer, so the question will show up as answered

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep separate objects, the way to rig is to select the object, shift select the armature, switch to *Pose* mode, select the bone to which you want to parent, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *(Set Parent to) Bone*.